# iterating over nester tuples to generate specific string

Tags: python, string, tuples

Hi I have a this mathematical equation:
"1 + (((-C24 + -A2 )^2) * (B2 - F4) " which I have converted to nested tuples like this while converting to prefix notation:

```
lis = ('add', '1', ('multiply', ('exp', ('add', '-C24', '-A2'), '2'), ('subtract', 'B2', 'F4')))
```

I want to convert it to a string that looks like this:

```
add(1, multiply(exp(add(-C24, -A2), 2), subtract(B2, F4)))
```

However, my output looks like this, which clearly isn't correct because I am missing some commas and parenthesis:

```
add(1, multiply(exp(add(-C24, -A2)2)subtract(B2, F4)
```

I am not sure if I programmed the loop for iterating over the nested tuples correctly to convert it to string:

```
    def solve(lis):
        count1 = 0;
        for element in lis:
            if isinstance(element, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(element,str):
                for x in solve(element):
                    yield x
            else:
                if count1 == 0:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 +="("
                    yield str1 
                elif count1 == 2:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 +=")"
                    yield str1 
                else:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 += ", "
                    yield str1 
                #yield str(element)
                print("element =", element, "count = ", count1)
            count1 = count1+1

print(''.join(list(solve(lis))))
```

Would appreciate any help in figuring out where I am messing up to generate the correct string.

Comment: What are the rules when generating the string? Define the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you reach an element that is an iterable, you don't put the "," or ")" after it. This would fix it (notice the if-else statement written in bold font inside your inner for-loop):

```
    def solve(lis):
        count1 = 0;
        for element in lis:
            if isinstance(element, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(element,str):
                for x in solve(element):
                    yield x
                if count1 == 2:
                    yield ")"
                else:
                    yield ", "

            else:
                if count1 == 0:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 +="("
                    yield str1 
                elif count1 == 2:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 +=")"
                    yield str1 
                else:
                    str1 = str(element)
                    str1 += ", "
                    yield str1 
                #yield str(element)
                print("element =", element, "count = ", count1)
            count1 = count1+1
```

Now this will print what you want:

```
print(''.join(list(solve(lis))))
```

Gives you:

```
add(1, multiply(exp(add(-C24, -A2), 2), subtract(B2, F4)))
```

As desired.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!